# Unknown error on HTTP request only in Chrome when body's size > 5 MB

Tags: .net, angular, google-chrome, http, request

Currently i make an HTTP request from my Angular to my .Net app which returns a FileResult treat like as a Blob in the front.
The response has a body of about 8MB and catch an error in Chrome but works well in Firefox and Edge.
When i divide the response size to about 5MB it works fine on Chrome, but my file is corrupted here.
I tried to find something on the web about browser's maximum http body size limit but without success.
Here is the exact error that Chrome is telling me:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"myurl","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/imagesacquisitions/consultation/25d7a4b8-da6e-476c-8630-8afc790c80ea: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}     at resolvePromise (zone.js:1262:1)     at zone.js:1169:1     at rejected (tslib.es6.js:74:89)     at push.23484._ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:409:1)     at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:25592:1)     at push.23484._ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:408:1)     at push.23484.Zone.run (zone.js:169:1)     at zone.js:1326:1     at push.23484._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:443:1)     at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25579:1)`

I specify that the back is well called and returns goods data (i remind that it works fine on Edge and Firefox), the Postman test concluded well too.
I installed Firefox yesterday to test this bug, so i don't have any configuration's parameter about it.

I tried to find if any size limit is present in Chrome, but it end with a No. I read that there is one but it's about 8KB so i think it's about request header and the fact was about 13 years old.
I can try to bypass the problem and divide my file to respond many little files instead of one big. But i want to know why is this problem there and understand it.

There is my angular code:

```
async getThumbnailById(id: string): Promise<string> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
      'Content-Type': 'image/*',
    });
   
    const res = await firstValueFrom(
      this.http.get(
        `myurl/${id}`,
        { headers, responseType: 'blob' }
      )
    );
```

My .Net code return a FileResult which has a FilsContents which is a byte[].

**Update**
It works fine on my friends computer, so i reinstalled Chrome, it works one time, but started to have old behavior right after.